# Lazy loading not working in mobile device chrome and safari browser?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

My code here:

```
`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $(window).scroll(function ()
   {
      if ((($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())) >= $(document).height())
      {
         setTimeout(function ()
         {
            scrollMore();
         }, 500);
      }
   });
   function scrollMore()
   {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() == (($(document).height()) - ($(window).height())))
      {
         var records =<?php echo $total_record; ?>;
         var offset = -Infinity;
         $(".limit").each(function ()
         {
            offset = Math.max(offset, parseFloat(this.value));
         });
         var query = $("#query").val();
         if (records >= offset)
         {
            $(window).unbind("scroll");
            $("#loading").show();
            setTimeout(function ()
            {
               loadMoreData(offset, query);
            }, 500);
            scrollTop: 0;
         }
      }
   }
   function loadMoreData(offset, query)
   {
      $("#loading").css('display', 'block');
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         async: false,
         url: 'get_data.php',
         data: {limit: offset, query: query},
         success: function (data)
         {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $('#posts').append(data);
         },
         error: function (data)
         {
            alert("ajax error occured" + data);
         }
      }).done(function ()
      {
         $(window).bind("scroll", function ()
         {
            scrollMore();
         });
      });
   }
</script>
```

this is perfect working in window and ubuntu in all responsive size desktop,tab,mobile(responsive width) but not working in mobile device chrome browser.

In mobile device mozila firefox browser working good.

Comment: What do you mean by “it's not working”? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No, it's working in desktop all browser but not working in some mobile devices (chrome browser).